# Rate not changing in AnyLogic Delay Component

Tags: anylogic

I have a Delay component which starts pulling out 50 per day from a queue, however that is driven by a parameter called capacityRate.

[image]

[image]

I have a cyclic event which changes capacityRate.  Even though I see capacityRate is increasing, I only see 50 at a time coming through the Delay component?

Answer (score 0):

This is a static parameter. To change it use the following in the event action field:

```
dailyProcessing.set_capacity((int)capacityRate);
```

What you write in the field you are showing doesn't matter much, it's the initial value only.

Check:

https://help.anylogic.com/topic/com.anylogic.help/html/processmodeling/changing-static.html?resultof=%22%73%65%74%22%20%22%63%61%70%61%63%69%74%79%22%20%22%63%61%70%61%63%22%20